# pvcreate: WARNING!

Tags: lvm, devices

I'm currently messing around creating LVMs on an external drive and think I may have deleted something by mistake!
When I run `pvcreate /dev/sdc1` to create my physical volume, I get this message:

```
WARNING: Device for PV 0JAtDx-VWuk-Xv7E-SVHl-saUz-5JFI-IQ4Jq6 not found or rejected by a filter.
```

Yet `pv` is still created?
Any ideas?

Comment: It is a warning not an error and can be due to a number of things such as your hard drive already containing a gpt partition table. Run `pvcreate -vvv ....` for more output.

Comment: Just curious to know, i've breezed through the man files but can't see -vvv, option, whats it's function?

Comment: more verbose output

Comment: Ok thanks! Well no warnings showed on that and I created the pv again and no warning showed this time!?

Comment: Hard to know as the warning itself is non-specific and can come form several sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some stale information, either in the kernel or cached by the LVM tools, about the data on `/dev/sdc` or `/dev/sdc1` that was suggesting this device is suspicious to be used as a PV storage.  Can you check the following commands if everything is as you expect them to be, and no errors show up?

```
dmesg|grep sdc
fdisk -l /dev/sdc
blkid
lsblk -f
```

(None of the above should change anything on any of the devices)

If it's about LVM's cache, you may need

```
pvscan --cache
```

to refresh it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer..  I ran all the above commands, with no errors.  Also ran pvscan --cache the warning still persists

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
sudo pvcreate -ff /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please [edit] your answer and add a bit more information about what this does and why you expect it to work?